# "Ext is not defined" issue in ExtJS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, firebug

I came across a "Ext is not defined" issue in ExtJS 4.
I am actually testing the example [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader) to starting learning ExtJS 4.

I have my example script file included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="orderRead.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="order.js"></script>
```

as well as these ExtJS script files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

but the problem is still there. Attached is the error message from Firebug: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the script tags for the Ext library before the script tags for your example files, so that they are loaded when your code runs.

Comment: And you should only need either `ext-all.js` or `ext-all-debug.js`, not both.

Comment: @ Guffa, That's it! Order matters! Thanks!

Comment: @ Johnny,  actually order is the matter. Yes, I only need one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the `ext-base.js` and `ext-all.js` files in following order.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
```